# Proper way of unloading/reloading a View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS and wondering how to **properly** implement view controller unloading/reloading.

Right now my app has a NavigationController with a MainMenuViewController (custom view controller) set up as root view controller. During the course of app lifetime, new ViewControllers are pushed/popped on the Navigation Controller. This works fine, the appropriate ViewControllers are initiated (from NIBs) the first time they are pushed to the stack.

However, I now want to unload one particular ViewController when it is popped, then reload it automatically when it is pushed again.

I have added a `[self release]` to that ViewControllers `viewDidDisappear:` and it unloads, but when i try to push the view again, i get a message sent to dealloc'ed instance error and crash. Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is that a proper way to unload a popped ViewController?
2. How to check if a given ViewController is loaded or not?
3. How to force a reload? With `loadWithNib:`, then push onto navigation stack?

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to iOS programming. Your crash is a memory management issue. It may take you a bit to get the hang of it but memory management gets way easier if you just follow one rule:

**an object needs to release anything it retains (alloc is equivalent to retain)**

In this case, your view controller is releasing itself and it definitely did not retain itself. Here's how the sequence works with a navigation controller:

1. The navigation controller is initialized with a root view controller (the first one on its stack). Lets call this `firstViewController`
2. A user action tells `firstViewController` to initialize `secondViewController` and push it onto the navigation controller. In most cases, `firstViewController` will release the instance of `secondViewController` after pushing it. At this point, `firstVC` is done with `secondVC`. The navigation controller is now retaining `secondVC`
3. User touches the back button on the navigation bar of `secondVC`. The navigation controller will pop `secondVC` from the stack and release it. As long as no other object is retaining it, `secondVC` will get be dealloc'ed.
4. Now user is back in `firstVC`. They can do the same user action which will init and push a new instance of `secondVC`.

Hope that helps a bit.

I'd also recommend you (re)read the Apple docs and look at the sample code referenced in the framework docs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but the example you've given is too basic for my case - I want to decide which viewcontrollers to dealloc and when (sometimes, even when it is popped, i want it to save it's state so when the user returns, it gets brought up immiediately). Right now i've worked around this, and set up MainView controller as a observer of notification center - and other view controllers post notifications if they want to be dealloc'ed or just popped from the stack.

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to do but I would still recommend reading and understanding the docs. Start simple and add complexity as you need it and things are working. Best of luck.